# Order By not working on MySql

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

Hi **Order By** not working on ***MySql***

the code is as follows,

```
select * from School where School.type = 'HighSchool' 
   order by (select locations.name from locations inner join School_locations 
      on locations.id = School_locations.location_id where 
         School_locations.School_id = School.id  and locations.location_country = 'US' limit 1)
```

and the output is displaying same for both ascending as well as descending how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'd need to do the subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM School s
    INNER JOIN School_locations sl ON (s.id = sl.School_id)
    INNER JOIN locations l ON (l.id = sl.location_id)
WHERE l.location_country = 'US' AND s.type = 'High school'
ORDER BY l.name
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy +1 for ur better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select school.* from school
    inner join school_locations on school_locations.schoolid = school.school_id
    inner join locations on locations.location.id = school_locations.locationid
where
    locations.location_country = 'US' and school.type = 'HighSchool'
order by
    locations.name
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
 select School.* from School inner join School_locations 
 on School_locations.School_id = School.id 
 inner join locations 
 on locations.id = School_locations.location_id
 where locations.location_country = 'US' and School.type = 'HighSchool' 
 order by locations.name limit 1
```